# How do I get the inner value to use as an array for gdb pretty print?

Tags: python, gdb, pretty-print

I wrote a pretty printer for InnerStruct which shows the array as 2 elements and the values correctly. I also made a joke one for TestStruct2, However I have no idea how to make TestStruct contain the same contents as InnerStruct. I have no idea how to access array.nestedVariables from gdb/python. How do I write this so TestStruct gives the same results as InnerStruct?

Source

```
struct InnerStruct
{
    int buffer[100];
    int len;
};
struct TestStruct
{
    InnerStruct array;
};
struct TestStruct2
{
    InnerStruct array;
};

int main() {
    TestStruct s;
    s.array.buffer[0] = 5;
    s.array.buffer[1] = 8;
    s.array.len=2;
    TestStruct2 s2;
    s2.array.buffer[0] = 5;
    s2.array.buffer[1] = 8;
    s2.array.len=2;
    return 0;
}
```

.gdbinit

```
python

pp = gdb.printing.RegexpCollectionPrettyPrinter("pp")

class InnerStructPrinter:
    "Print a InnerStruct"

    class _iterator:
        def __init__ (self, start, finish):
            self.item = start
            self.finish = finish
            self.count = 0

        def __iter__ (self):
            return self

        def __next__ (self):
            count = self.count
            self.count = self.count + 1
            if self.item == self.finish:
                raise StopIteration
            elt = self.item.dereference()
            self.item = self.item + 1
            return ('[%d]' % count, elt)

        def next (self):
            return self.__next__()

    def __init__ (self, val):
        self.val = val

    def children (self):
        start = self.val['buffer'][0].address
        return self._iterator(start, start + self.val['len'])

    def to_string (self):
        len = self.val['len']
        return '%s of length %d' % (self.val.type, len)

    def display_hint (self):
        return 'array'

pp.add_printer('InnerStruct', '^InnerStruct$', InnerStructPrinter)

class TestStruct2Printer:
    "Print a TestStruct2"

    def __init__ (self, val):
        self.val = val

    def to_string (self):
        return "Array of"

    def children(self):
        yield ('0', 'fake')
        yield ('1', 'val')

    def display_hint (self):
        return 'array'

pp.add_printer('TestStruct2', '^TestStruct2$', TestStruct2Printer)

gdb.printing.register_pretty_printer(gdb.current_objfile(), pp)
end
```

Comment: Can you please add the info how the result looks like now, and how you want it to look exactly?

Comment: What is array.nestedVariables? I don't see `nestedVariables` anywhere in the code.

Comment: @ssbssa I want TestStruct to look EXACTLY THE SAME as InnerStruct. The gdbinit has that working perfectly but my question is getting TestStruct to look like it. I can't figure out how to pull the variables from the member to recreate it

Comment: @ks1322 I didn't mean 'nestedVariables' literally. I mean the variables inside a variable. For InnerStruct I can access buffer and length just fine but for TestStruct to make it look the same I would have to get array.buffer/array.length and I have absolutely no idea how to access those variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t see a reason why adding this wouldn’t be sufficient.

```python
class TestStructPrinter(InnerStructPrinter):
    def __init__(self, val):
        super().__init__(val['array'])

pp.add_printer('TestStruct', '^TestStruct$', TestStructPrinter)
```

In other words, the sub-fields are accessed simply as `val['field']['subfield']`. The subclassing is something of a hack, but you get the idea.

Sample session:

```text
(gdb) show version 
GNU gdb (Debian 9.2-1) 9.2
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
[…]
(gdb) python print(sys.version)
3.8.6 (default, Sep 25 2020, 09:36:53) 
[GCC 10.2.0]
(gdb) print s
$1 = InnerStruct of length 2 = {5, 8}
(gdb) print s.array
$2 = InnerStruct of length 2 = {5, 8}
```

This seems a rather silly thing to do, though: a debugger is supposed to help you tell types apart. By making `TestStruct` and `InnerStruct` print out the same, it will instead mislead the user into thinking one type is being used instead of the other, and have them attempt to access, say, `s.buffer` instead of `s.array.buffer`.

Comment: I'll have to get back to you tomorrow when I actually try this but does `val['field']['subfield']` actually work? I could swear I tried that more than once

Comment: This was bothering me enough that I tried it. Something went wrong. Is it only those 4 lines? Because adding it in makes `.gdbinit` break and not load any pretty printers.

Comment: Well, no, you put it between the `python` command and the `end` which terminates it. (And after the superclass, of course.)

Comment: I guess it was a paste problem. It appears to work and so does `val['field']['subfield']` which I could swear I tried. In the morning I'll try applying this to my real class and see if it works and I'll let you know if I have any follow up questions. I'll likely accept as it is

Comment: This definitely works (`val['field']['subfield']`). Accepted. It was enough that I figured out how to make a map pretty print so my gdbinit problems are all solved. TY